# How to duplicate data somewhere between a file using dd command in Unix?

Tags: linux, unix, embedded-linux, dd

```
3601787       0x36F57B        HTML document header
3619359       0x373A1F        HTML document footer
3631100       0x3767FC        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3631152       0x376830        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3631220       0x376874        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3631564       0x3769CC        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3637524       0x378114        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3637576       0x378148        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3637608       0x378168        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3637764       0x378204        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3637796       0x378224        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3638136       0x378378        Zlib compressed data, default compression
3654196       0x37C234        PNG image, 160 x 160, 8-bit grayscale, non-interlaced
3654237       0x37C25D        Zlib compressed data, best compression
3655880       0x37C8C8        GIF image data, version "89a", 18 x 18
```

Here I only want to get the Zlib compressed data separately...

`dd if=sourcefile.bin skip=3631100 bs=1 of=output.zlib` will skip to the given location then copy everything after it, but that is not what I want.

I want to separate all 11 Zlib compressed data from the sourcefile...
Please suggest the right command to do that.

Comment: `dd` is not the right command.  Superficially, it looks like a job for `grep`: `grep 'Zlib compressed data,' sourcefile.bin > output.zlib`.  Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: `dd` comes with a `count` parameter as well.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It sounds for me as if Mikku would want to use the first column of this reference file to slice another file based on byte count.

Comment: Then the question is inadequately describing what is required, @ypnos.  I can't say you're wrong — there is just enough plausibility that you may be right. If so, there needs to be a length for the subsection of the data, but the hex number seems to be the same value as the first column, so it appears that the length information is not present.  Maybe it has to be deduced by looking at the next entry and subtracting the difference to come up with a size (all except for the last file in the source file).

Comment: That's what I would assume. This will only work if there is always another entry after the last Zlib one.

Comment: so `count` parameter will count to specified lenght of data? plz give an example @ypnos

Comment: The example would be `dd if=sourcefile.bin bs=1 skip=3631100 count=52 of=output.zlib`. Now onto computing the number.

Comment: it's not a text file and I'm not finding any pattern so that i need grep instead :p @JonathanLeffler